# Parse notification displayed, open action doesn't start activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, parse-platform, push-notification

I have some Parse code that receives push data and sets up a notification which works fine but the problem is the onPushOpen declaration. I want to open a specific activity in my app but onPushOpen seems to never get called or just not work?

This is my code:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MYTAG";


   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification received");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data") : "";
        JSONObject jObject;
        String alert = null;
        String title = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(message);
            alert = (jObject.getString("alert"));
            title = (jObject.getString("title"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(TAG,"alert is " + alert);
        Log.i(TAG,"title is " + title);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(alert)
                        .setContentText(title);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification created");

   }


    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why onPushOpen doesn't start my requested activity (MainActivity). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No error. Just nothing happening upon pushing/tapping/clicking the notification

Comment: Do you know for a fact that `onPushOpen()` is being called?

Comment: I do not. As far as I found in parse docs onPushOpen is called when you click the notification. However I do not see the log message I wrote at the start of the method...

Answer (score 1):

i'm facing the same problem with the `onPushOpen()` method, but if you just want to open your activity, there is a little work around. you can solve the problem by using a [Pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(alert)
                    .setContentText(title);

// create intent to start your activity
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

// create pending intent and add activity intent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// Add as notification
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

so it is not necessary to call the `onPushOpen()` method, because as soon as the notification gets clicked the pending intent starts your activity.